# JQuery + MVC 3: Client-Side Dynamic Data Binding to Html.DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, data-binding, drop-down-menu, client-side

I have a "Create User" form where a user can have any number of roles. Hence I decided to add a dropdownlist which is populated by roles and add an "Add" link/button next:

```
<label for="Role">Roles</label>
@Html.DropDownList("Roles", new SelectList((IEnumerable<RoleSummaryView>)ViewData["Roles"], "Id", "Name")) 
<div>
    <a href="#" class="ym-gbox tbalign" style="padding-top:3px;">Add</a>
    <a href="#" class="ym-gbox tbalign" style="padding-top:3px;">Delete</a>
</div>
```

In this scenario it is supposed that when "Add" is clicked another dropdownlist populated with the same roles data and another "Add" and "Delete" links/buttons next to the list should be added in a new line. Now if the user clicks to any "Add" the same process will be repeated. If the user clicks to "Delete" the dropdownlist next to the link/button should be gone.

I've tried to write the javascript code and the controller with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should an list or array for binding selected values on server-side.

```
ActionResult MyActionName(List<int> SelectedRoles){

}
```

---------------View----------------

```
<script>
     var index = 0;
     $("#addButton").click(function(){
            var newSelect = $("<select id='SelectedRoles["+ index +"]' name='SelectedRoles["+ index +"]'></select>");
            $('#SelectedRoles[0] option').each(function(){
                 var option = $("<option></option>").val($(this).val()).text($(this).text());
                 newSelect.append(option);
            });

            $("#newSelectContainer").append(newSelect);

            index++;
     });
     $("#removeButton").click(function(){
          $("SelectedRoles["+ --index +"]").remove();
     })
</script>


<label for="Role">Roles</label>
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRoles[0]", new SelectList((IEnumerable<RoleSummaryView>)ViewData["Roles"], "Id", "Name")) 
<div>
    <a href="#" class="ym-gbox tbalign" style="padding-top:3px;" id="addButton">Add</a>
    <a href="#" class="ym-gbox tbalign" style="padding-top:3px;" id="removeButton">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It does add new dropdownlists but unfortunately with no data.

Comment: Interestingly, in the working html code the id of the dropdownlist became to "SelectedRoles_0_" and while the javascript was looking for "SelectedRoles[0]" it founds the first added dropdownlist only, because the index started from 0. So I changed the Id to only SelectedRoles and it started to work. Thank you for the code Yorgo.. Now as the second part of my question, I will try to bind those dropdownlist values to my model's collection attribute.

Comment: if you wanna bind selected values of dynamicly created select items then you should use list item.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like this

```
$(myAddButton).bind("click", function(){

$(aDiv).append("<select id='aUniqueId'></select>");
$('#myOriginalSelect option').each(function(item){

$('aUniqueId').append('<option value=' + $(this).value + '>' + $(this).text + '</option>')';

});
```

}

and for delete

```
$('#myUniqueDelete').bind("click", function(){

$('myUniqueSelect').remove();

})
```

I'm sure the code needs some tweaks, but I hope it is useful